# conditionally using a secondary threshold level

Tags: r, data.table

I try to find a solution for the following problem I ran into, however the dataset I am using substantial, thus I am trying to avoid to many loops etc. I have two identifiers, var1 and var2, which combined with the date is unique. Furthermore, I have var3 which is a value between 0.5 (0.5 is a threshold value) and infinity. I try to calculate the change from one date to another in var3 for each combination of var1, var2, which I have done using this line of code, which works like a charm:

```
test = test[, test_change := var3 - shift(var3, type = "lag", n = 1), by = c("var1", "var2")]
```

However, the results are incorrect for cases in which var3 was already higher than the threshold of 0.5 at date “2016-01-01”, in that case I would like to use the value of var3 at “2016-01-01” as the threshold until it drops to or below the 0.5 threshold. This only has to be done if the starting date is “2016-01-01”. Additionally, the change cannot be larger than the distance between the value and the threshold, so the part it drops below the threshold is omitted, as in row 5 where var3 drops from 1.5 to 0.6 for (a, X) but the temporary threshold is 1, hence the change should be equal to -0.5.

**Data**

```
test = data.table(Date = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-01","2016-01-3", "2016-01-05", "2016-01-05", "2016-01-06", "2016-01-06", "2016-01-07")), var1 = c("a", "a", "b","a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a"), var2 = c("X", "Y","X", "X", "X", "Y", "X", "X", "X"), var3 = c(1,0.75,0.5,1.5, 0.6,1.2, 0.55, 0.50, 0.75))

> test
         Date var1 var2 var3
1: 2016-01-01    a    X 1.00
2: 2016-01-01    a    Y 0.75
3: 2016-01-01    b    X 0.50
4: 2016-01-03    a    X 1.50
5: 2016-01-05    a    X 0.60
6: 2016-01-05    a    Y 1.20
7: 2016-01-06    b    X 0.55
8: 2016-01-06    a    X 0.50
9: 2016-01-07    a    X 0.75
```

**Expected outcome**

```
test = data.table(Date = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-01","2016-01-3", "2016-01-05", "2016-01-05", "2016-01-06", "2016-01-06", "2016-01-07")), var1 = c("a", "a", "b","a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a"), var2 = c("X", "Y","X", "X", "X", "Y", "X", "X", "X"), var3 = c(1,0.75,0.5,1.5, 0.6,1.2, 0.55, 0.50, 0.75), change_var3 = c(0,0,0,0.5,-0.5,0.45,0.05,0,0.25))

> test
         Date var1 var2 var3 change_var3
1: 2016-01-01    a    X 1.00        0.00
2: 2016-01-01    a    Y 0.75        0.00
3: 2016-01-01    b    X 0.50        0.00
4: 2016-01-03    a    X 1.50        0.50
5: 2016-01-05    a    X 0.60       -0.50
6: 2016-01-05    a    Y 1.20        0.45
7: 2016-01-06    b    X 0.55        0.05
8: 2016-01-06    a    X 0.50        0.00
9: 2016-01-07    a    X 0.75        0.25
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my own problem and hopefully I can help someone else out with my solution.

```
library(data.table)
test = data.table(Date = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-01","2016-01-3", "2016-01-05", "2016-01-05", "2016-01-06", "2016-01-06", "2016-01-07","2016-01-08")), var1 = c("a", "a", "b","a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "a"), var2 = c("X", "Y","X", "X", "X", "Y", "X", "X", "X", "X"), var3 = c(1,0.75,0.5,1.5, 0.6,1.2, 0.55, 0.50, 0.75, 0.4))
test[var3 <= 0.5, var3 := 0.5]
test[, test_threshold := ifelse(Date == "2016-01-01", var3, NA)]
test[, test :=  ifelse(var3 > 0.5 & (shift(var3, n = 1, type = "lag")> 0.5 |is.na(shift(var3, n = 1, type = "lag")) == TRUE) , test_threshold[1], 0.5), by = c("var1", "var2")]
test[, var5 := var3 - test]
test[var5 < 0, var5 := 0]
test[, var5_change := var5 - shift(var5, n = 1, type = "lag"),
     by = c("var1", "var2")]

> test
          Date var1 var2 var3 test_threshold test var5 var5_change
 1: 2016-01-01    a    X 1.00           1.00 1.00 0.00          NA
 2: 2016-01-01    a    Y 0.75           0.75 0.75 0.00          NA
 3: 2016-01-01    b    X 0.50           0.50 0.50 0.00          NA
 4: 2016-01-03    a    X 1.50             NA 1.00 0.50        0.50
 5: 2016-01-05    a    X 0.60             NA 1.00 0.00       -0.50
 6: 2016-01-05    a    Y 1.20             NA 0.75 0.45        0.45
 7: 2016-01-06    b    X 0.55             NA 0.50 0.05        0.05
 8: 2016-01-06    a    X 0.50             NA 0.50 0.00        0.00
 9: 2016-01-07    a    X 0.75             NA 0.50 0.25        0.25
10: 2016-01-08    a    X 0.50             NA 0.50 0.00       -0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope understand your conditions the right way.

The main thing I changed was to create the shifted variable as additional column to work with and then calculate the lag with your given conditions.
I assumed the first given value of var3 is the temporary threshold to compare the data to by group, so it's the `NA`value of the lagged variable.
Then I updated the change column with your other conditions: set `var3` to 0, if it is below a certain threshold or if it's the first value.

```
test = data.table(
  Date = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-01","2016-01-3", "2016-01-05", "2016-01-05", "2016-01-06", "2016-01-06", "2016-01-07")), 
  var1 = c("a", "a", "b","a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a"), 
  var2 = c("X", "Y","X", "X", "X", "Y", "X", "X", "X"), 
  var3 = c(1,0.75,0.5,1.5, 0.6,1.2, 0.55, 0.50, 0.75), 
  change_var3 = c(0,0,0,0.5,-0.5,0.45,0.05,0,0.25))

test[, var3_lag := c(NA, var3[-.N]), by = c("var1", "var2")]
test[, test_change := ifelse(var3_lag > var3[is.na(var3_lag)], 
                              var3[is.na(var3_lag)] - var3_lag, 
                              var3 - var3_lag), 
     by = c("var1", "var2")]

test[is.na(var3_lag) | var3 <= 0.5, test_change := 0]
```

which results in:

```
> test
         Date var1 var2 var3 change_var3 var3_lag test_change
1: 2016-01-01    a    X 1.00        0.00       NA        0.00
2: 2016-01-01    a    Y 0.75        0.00       NA        0.00
3: 2016-01-01    b    X 0.50        0.00       NA        0.00
4: 2016-01-03    a    X 1.50        0.50     1.00        0.50
5: 2016-01-05    a    X 0.60       -0.50     1.50       -0.50
6: 2016-01-05    a    Y 1.20        0.45     0.75        0.45
7: 2016-01-06    b    X 0.55        0.05     0.50        0.05
8: 2016-01-06    a    X 0.50        0.00     0.60        0.00
9: 2016-01-07    a    X 0.75        0.25     0.50        0.25
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Thank you psuhing me in the right direction. Your solution was not totally what I was after, but I managed to solve it myself.